# Error: unexpected '>' in ">" . Trying to create a data frame

Tags: r

```r
metallica<-data.frame(Name = metallicaNames, Age = metallicaAges)
```

That's my exact code. I don't see a '>' anywhere. I know the '<' is correct. Where and what is my problem? I'm fairly new to R.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you accidentally copy and past code from a tutorial/resource that had a leading ">" symbol? The ">" often denotes the R prompt. Check that `metallica <- data.frame(Name = letters[1:3], Age = 1:3)` works.

Answer (score -1):

You need quotes around your strings, e.g.
metallica<-data.frame(Name = "metallicaNames", Age = "metallicaAges")

Comment: I assume `metallicaNames` and `metallicaAges` are variables in OP's global environment, presumably referring to a `character` and `numeric` vector... I'm not sure what you suggest is what OP is after.